# Rails - order by hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, sqlite, heroku

```
@events = Event.all(:order => "date DESC")
```

to order my events by date, a `datetime` column.

Is it possible to order them not by date, but only by hour? (I'm suing `sqlite3` database)

Thanks!

Comment: which db are you using? mysql?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For SQLite,

```
@events = Event.all(:order => "time(date) DESC")
```

Use that with care, because it ignores the date. (And see "Moments later" below.)

```
CREATE TABLE test (date datetime primary key);
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES('2011-01-01 08:00:00');
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES('2011-01-01 08:13:00');
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES('2011-01-01 09:23:00');
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES('2011-01-02 09:15:00');
```

Only one of the dates is on Jan 2.

```
sqlite> select * from test order by time(date) desc;
2011-01-01 09:23:00
2011-01-02 09:15:00
2011-01-01 08:13:00
2011-01-01 08:00:00
```

**Moments later . . .**

I realized you wanted to sort by hour, not by time. That questionable requirement takes a different expression, and sorts differently.

```
@events = Event.all(:order => "strftime('%H', date) DESC")

sqlite> select date from test order by strftime('%H', date) desc;
2011-01-01 09:23:00
2011-01-02 09:15:00
2011-01-01 08:00:00
2011-01-01 08:13:00
```

The last two rows are sorted correctly by hour, incorrectly by time.

**Still later . . .**

The OP deploys on Heroku, which doesn't support SQLite. To sort by hour descending, the OP probably needs something like

```
@events = Event.all(:order => "extract (hour from date) DESC")
```

And stop using one platform for development and a different platform for deployment.

Comment: Hi Catcall, thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately your suggestion is good using a local server, but doesn't work on Heroku, that claims for a syntax error

Comment: If you're deploying on Heroku, you shouldn't be developing against SQLite. Install PostgreSQL, and use that as your development platform.

Comment: I wish I could give you more than one upvote for "stop using one platform for development and a different platform for deployment", there should be a Markdown macro for that. I think Heroku should check your `database.yml` and scream at you if your development adapter is anything other than PostgreSQL.

Comment: @mu is too short: Well, I wish you could give me more than one upvote, too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since Heroku uses PostgreSQL, you can use:

```
@events = Event.all(:order => "date_part(hour, date) DESC")
```

You'll have problems developing if you use SQLite3 locally and PostgreSQL for deployment - SQL is not consistent between platforms.